# Selenium Testing xpath

Tags: java, selenium

Hey i need this xpath for list

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post the complete list with its item ? Also post your html code instead of a screenshot, it will be easier for us to test our solution.

Comment: Can you not just right click on the element copy xpath if all you want is the xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first click on `My Account` link and then need to click `Login` or `Sign Up` link.

Induce [WebDriverWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and `elementToBeClickable` with following xpath.

To click on `Login` link

> Click on My Account

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement eleMyaccount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse navbar-collapse']//ul//li[@id='li_myaccount']//a[contains(.,'My Account')]//i")));
eleMyaccount.click()
```

> Click on Login link

```
WebElement eleLogin = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse navbar-collapse']//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//li//a[contains(.,'Login')]")));
eleLogin.click()
```

---

To click on `Sign Up` link

> Click on My Account

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement eleMyaccount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse navbar-collapse']//ul//li[@id='li_myaccount']//a[contains(.,'My Account')]//i")));
eleMyaccount.click()
```

> Click on Sign Up link

```
WebElement eleSignUp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse navbar-collapse']//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//li//a[contains(.,'Sign Up')]")));
eleSignUp.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

get `li` tag with attribute `id` **li_myaccount** and then get its parent `ul` tag using `ancestor::tagName`

```
//li[@id='li_myaccount']//ancestor::ul
```

This should be what you are looking for :)

Comment: After run the code then this error message appears.  I used your xpath

Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='li_myaccount']//ancestor::ul")));
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  //s.selectByVisibleText("Login");
  s.selectByIndex(1);

Comment: in your code you are choosing a <select> tag however here we are dealing witjh an Unordered list <ul>

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "ul"
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'NAV-L186', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:48)
 at day0.Day0.main(Day0.java:27)

Comment: This exception shows that we found the <ul> correctly however you need a diffrent approach for it than you do for <select>

Comment: Select class accepts WebElement if it is found correctly then it should work.

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

Comment: This documentation says that Select() class is made for <select> tags

Comment: Of course <select> tag is also handled as a WebElement in code

Comment: can u  add full html screen of both the drop down elements ?

Comment: @AmitJain, yes sure

Comment: @AmitJain all are uploaded HTML and page link:https://www.phptravels.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
By populateDropDown= By.xpath("(//a[@data-toggle='dropdown']/i)[2]");
By loginOption = By.xpath("(//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li[1]/a[1])[2]");
By signUpOption = By.xpath("(//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li[2]/a[1])[2]");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// Populate drop down
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(populateDropDown);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropDown));
dropDown.click();

// Click login
WebElement login = driver.findElement(loginOption)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(login));
login.click();

// OR click signUpOption
WebElement signUp = driver.findElement(signUpOption);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(signUp));
signUp.click();
```

Comment: not working again error message is appearing Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@data-toggle='dropdown']/i)[2] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[@data-toggle='dropdown']/i)[2]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @zafarahmad => I changed xpath, a bracket was missing , can you check now ?